# Can someone please tell me why the two python codes below produce entirely different outcomes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Here is my code :

```
>>> hellos = [ "hello", "bonjour", "hola"]                                                                     
>>> for hi in hellos:                                                                                          
...     print(hi + " World!")                                                                                  
...                                                                                                            
hello World!                                                                                                   
bonjour World!                                                                                                 
hola World! 


>>> hellos = [ "hello", "bonjour", "hola"]                                                                     
>>> for hi in hellos:                                                                                          
...     print("hi" + " World!")                                                                                
...                                                                                                            
hi World!                                                                                                      
hi World!                                                                                                      
hi World!
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting

Comment: What do you expect the outputs to be?

Comment: Because when you enclose something inside `"..."` it's a string

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - might be a good start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second time, hi is in quotes. So it is a string literal. It is not a variable. Specifically, it is not the value of the iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you add value of hellos `i.e hi` with `" World!"`

```
print(hi + " World!")
```

So, output is :

```
hello World!
bonjour World!
hola World!
```

Secondly, you just concatenate `"hi"` with `" World!"` .

```
print("hi" + " World!")
```

So, output is :

```
hi World!
hi World!
hi World!
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just concatinating strings in the second one

"hi" + " World!" = hi World!